# iOS temporarily disable Page View Controller swiping

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a setup where I have a `Page View Controller` set up to navigate between different `views`.

In some of these views I will have a `custom drawing view` where the user can draw with their finger to create a picture.

The problem with this, the user is not able to make a drawing gesture `left/right` because the `page view controller` will take over and navigate to a different view.

I was wondering what a good approach would be to temporarily disable the `swiping` for the `page view controller` to allow the user to `draw`.

I was thinking when the user first interacts with the `drawing view` it would disable the `page swiping` and create a `finished drawing button`. When this button is clicked it would reenable the `page swiping`. Does this seem reasonable, or does anybody know of any better approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can stop Scrolling

```
for (UIScrollView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {

if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {

    view.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into this `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```

Here you can "kill" the page view controller's gesture recognizer by disabling and re-enabling it:

```
if (/* otherGestureRecognizer is page view controller's */) {
    otherGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    otherGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
}
```